# What are the category and monoids given rise to by a monad?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, monads

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Definition

> Given any well-defined, basic types T, U, a monad consists of three
>   parts:
>
> - A type constructor $M$ that builds up a monadic type $M T$
> - A type converter, often called $unit$ or $return$, that embeds an object $x$ in the monad:
>
>   $$unit(x) : T → M T$$
> - A combinator, typically called $bind$ (as in binding a variable) and represented with an infix operator $>>=$, that unwraps a monadic
>     variable, then inserts it into a monadic function/expression,
>     resulting in a new monadic value: $$(mx >>= f) : (M T, T → M U) → M
>   > U$$
>
> To fully qualify as a monad though, these three parts must also
>   respect a few laws:
>
> - $unit$ is a left-identity for $bind$:  $$unit(a) >>= λx → f(x) ↔ f(a)$$
> - $unit$ is also a right-identity for $bind$:
>     $$ma >>= λx → unit(x) ↔ ma$$
> - $bind$ is essentially associative:
>     $$ma >>= λx → (f(x) >>= λy → g(y)) ↔ (ma >>= λx → f(x)) >>= λy → g(y)$$
>
> Algebraically, this means any monad both gives rise to **a category**
>   (called the Kleisli category) and **a monoid in the category of
>   functors (from values to computations), with monadic composition as a
>   binary operator and unit as identity**.

Questions:

1. What is the "category" given rise to by a monad? Specifically, what are the objects and morphisms in the "category"?
2. What is the monoid given rise to by a monad?
   When the quote says "a monoid in the category of functors (from values to computations)", what does it mean by "a monoid in the category of functors" and "functors (from values to computations)"?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend ignoring this description of monads from Wikipedia, especially if you are more interested in the mathematics. In fact, I'd recommend against that entire Wikipedia page. It reads more like someone wrote a blog article into a Wikipedia entry (and not particularly well...) In just the part you're quoting, there are subtle issues that make some of the statements false, and then, there are outright mistakes (plus vague and confusing language), in particular about the "monoid" stuff.

Comment: At any rate, it sounds like the author is trying to refer to the description of monads as monoid objects in the category of endofunctors but has completely fumbled it. To understand this, you need to understand a generalization of the notion of a monoid, because you don't get a normal, set-theoretic monoid. The multiplication there isn't "monadic composition" (which doesn't get defined until later) though. Alternatively, it could be talking about a monoid of endomorphisms in the Kleisli category, but this is uninteresting and still incorrectly described. It's not in a "category of functors".

Comment: I would recommend completely forgetting about this definition of a monad, looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory), and then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category, or any section on monads in any standard text on category theory.